# How to copy text from iOS to MacOS with Bluetooth only (no WiFi network at all)?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, copy-paste

I'd like to be able to copy text from iOS to MacOS with Bluetooth only (no WiFi) — or, worst case, by plugging the phone into the Mac.

I often find myself generating text on my phone (in various apps, it doesn't matter, the text can be copied to the iOS clipboard) while offline and then wanting to transfer it to my Mac for further editing. I can't use Universal Clipboard because that requires both devices to be on a WiFi network. There is an iOS and companion MacOS app called [Scribe](http://usescribe.com) that enables copying text via Bluetooth, but only from the Mac to the iOS device. I want to the other way around.

Is there a way to copy text from iOS (latest version, iOS 12.3.1 on, in this case, an iPhone 8) to MacOS (Mojave 10.14.5, on a 13" Macbook Pro) with Bluetooth only (no WiFi network at all)?

Comment: What app are you using for generating the text on your iOS device?

Comment: You would need to use a 3rd party application.  If you update your question to include the versions of all impacted devices as well as see [this Meta post about asking for software recommendations](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313), maybe someone has info that could help you.

Comment: @NimeshNeema it doesn't matter what app -- it would just be text copied to the iOS clipboard...

Comment: @fsb OK thx I added a bit more detail

Comment: macOS does support downstream wifi.  That is macOS will act like a router. system preferences > sharing. check Internet Sharing.  Share your connection from Ethernet. To computers using wifi.  I haven't done this in awhile.